# Capturing Policy Url on CombinedSignInAndSignUp page in Azure B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to capture the URL of the Azure B2C custom policy as user lands on the first page. This is the CombinedSignInAndSignUp orchestration step (the first combined signup/sign-in page). I want to use this url at later stage during the user journey.
I'm fiddling with the idea of displaying a pop-up with custom message if anything goes wrong and journey can not be continued further. 
Current recommendation from Microsoft is that it throws an error and backend application should handle that error and take appropriate action (like in the case of Forgot Password link). I'm trying to handle this situation slightly different in the sense that I'd rather show this message to the user and redirect back to the policy (sign-up or password reset).

I have tried to setup extra input controls on CombinedSignInAndSignUp step but it doesn't seem to support that, it's only showing username and password controls. The idea was I capture current url (via JavaScript), store it in that input control (claim) and carry it forward in the journey and use it when needed to redirect the user back to that policy.

Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the url can be captured or not  but its easy o construct it using `claims transformations` and [claim resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview).

Following will be the format of the policy url with all the claim resolver  mentioned. You will need a claims transformation to format the final url .
    https://{Policy:RelyingPartyTenantId}.b2clogin.com/{Policy:RelyingPartyTenantId}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={Policy:PolicyId}&client_id={OIDC:ClientId}&nonce={OIDC:Nonce}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope{OIDC:scope}&response_type=id_token&prompt={OIDC:Prompt}&ui_locales={Culture:LanguageName}

There are two variables which currently are not available in custom policy as a claims resolver- redirect_uri and responseType. For them you have two options
- Hard code them
- duplicate them into other query string param to the policy url and then extract them as claims resolver. B2C has claims resolver which can get value from query string params it's called {OAUTH-KV} claims resolver. example for a query string parameter testReplyUrl.

```
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="replyUrl" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:testReplyUrl}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />

<BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="replyUrl">
        <DisplayName>redirect uri</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Reply url</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>ReplyUrl.</UserHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, 
Thanks for your response. I considered this but in my scenario, I can't hardcode the replyUrl as this could be different (based on if a web app is calling or native app). But I'll think about this approach to see if I can make it work. Thanks for the suggestion.